# Please define "link only answer"

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

There have been a few times now where I've flagged what I understand to be a link only answer only to have it disputed or declined, even after a second moderator flag has been raised.

[image: Moderator flag declined on link only answer]

---

As far as I can find, there is no official definitive definition for a link only answer. However, the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page does say this about links:

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Further, the low quality queue provides this comment on answers specified as *Link only*:

> “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Even the meta-tag [link-only-answers] loosely states what a link only answer is:

> Link only answers are answers that are barely more than a link to another page.

---

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848641/are-there-strongly-typed-collections-in-objective-c/17999958#17999958) being addressed in the above screenshot would be absolutely useless by itself.

> Take a look at:
>
> https://github.com/tomersh/Objective-C-Generics
>
> It appears to be a sort of poor-man's generics, by repurposing the protocol checking mechanism.

Let's take a look at what the answer would essentially be if the link went down (keeping in mind the linked repository hasn't been touched in 2 years to begin with):

> Take a look at:
>
> It appears to be a sort of poor-man's generics, by repurposing the protocol checking mechanism.

---

Unless I'm misunderstanding how this site works (after 679 helpful flags I would hope that's not the case), this link should have been a comment. [At least one other user agrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848641/are-there-strongly-typed-collections-in-objective-c/17999958#comment45050813_17999958), too.

---

So what, pray tell, is a **link only answer**, then?

Comment: Just a question for you, if you flagged it as NAA and it was disputed by the community, why do you feel it is urgent enough that a moderator needs to be involved?  The community disagreed with your original flag, if you don't like the answer - downvote and move along.  IMO, this is not something a moderator needs to get involved in.

Comment: @bluefeet because to me this is a **blatant** example of a link only answer. I've yet to get any clear answer as to how it is not. I've just been linked to other places and told "it's useful, so it's staying".

Comment: @gnat `This includes many link-only answers; posts that try to answer the question by pointing at a keyword that happens to be a link, or similar.` - This answer isn't a keyword that happens to be a link. It's just a link.

Comment: "See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

The rule-of-thumb here is to strip the markup; if you can still regard it as an (attempted) answer without the link, it is still an answer and should not be flagged..."

Comment: @gnat I did that in my post. Can you honestly tell me the answer stripped of the link is at all useful?

Comment: well I checked the answer,other answers in there, question and comments and I can't make up my mind. "It appears to be a (_[provided link makes this statement sound like 'it can be done as']_) sort of poor-man's generics, by repurposing the protocol checking mechanism". I wouldn't want moderators to use their powers deciding whether to keep such answers or delete

Comment: The line under the link does nothing to describe *how* that is done. That line itself is a vague summation of what the link is. It doesn't allow the OP to google it later in order to figure it out in the case of the link going dead.

Comment: You're mistaken on what the answer would look like once the link breaks. The URL isn't going to vanish into thin air. It's just going to end in a 404 if you tried to click on it.

Comment: @BoltClock and what use would it have as an answer then?

Comment: @Qix: None still, but for the reason that the primary or sole purpose of the answer is to be a link to an external resource, which isn't quite the same as "this answer contains no information on its own". Maybe we should add that to the definition of "link-only answer" - it makes sense, and besides, questions asking for link answers are off-topic for the same reason anyway.

Comment: While I agree that this text may need to be added, this answer *doesn't* provide any information on its own.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I don't agree with your closure of this. The dupe target you've chosen asks specifically about when "Not An Answer" flags should be used, but the link-only reason asked about here is displayed in the LQ review queue, which is mostly populated by LQ flags or system-generated flags, not by NAA flags. The linked question barely intersects with this one, and your answer there certainly doesn't answer this. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

A link-only answer is an answer that contains no information apart from a link to another site. The hallmark of a link-only answer is that it is impossible to evaluate even the potential usefulness of the answer without actually following the link.

It notably does *not* mean "a short answer containing a link", although folks are often confused.

The reason for declining your flag seems self-explanatory; the answer is recommending a library, which it describes *and* links to. There is no form of that answer that would still be valid if that link broke, save one that linked to the same library on a *different* site (maybe a mirror on Google Co...oh).

#### See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: `The reason for declining your flag seems self-explanatory; the answer is recommending a library, which it describes and links to. There is no form of that answer that would still be valid if that link broke, save one that linked to the same library on a different site (maybe a mirror on Google Co...oh).` How are those not two contradicting statements? **The answer would be useless without that link.** The answers that were given as examples in your linked topic would not be.

Comment: Difference between "there might be beer down the street" and "the house beer at tomersh's pub is good".

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: @Qix: The first statement says nothing about the beer except that it exists somewhere. The second statement tells you something about that beer so you don't have to go through the trouble of traveling all the way there just to find out if it is good.

Comment: @BoltClock But the whole issue with link-only answers is that if the link breaks, the answer is worthless. The beer at Tomersh's pub might have been great, with complex hop undertones and a rich body, when the answer was given, but if Tomersh's closes or changes its name or can't be found on Google maps, then the answer (and its description) has no value. Likewise, if Tomersh closes his GitHub or the link is otherwise broken, the answer, even with its description, is worthless.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard ^ exactly.