# Clarification on failed audit of "link only answer"

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

I recently failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11066138) & was immediately review banned for 2 days. I'll probably be too busy over the weekend here to review anyway so that's not a big deal. However it would be nice to clarify my stance on link only answers to avoid this happening again & get flagging posts more efficiently.

I read through Shog9's [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288055/please-define-link-only-answer) and the ['Answer and Apples'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) comparison and then decided that the post did contain an answer (albeit a short/crappy one). The author describes that his solution is an algorithm based on truth tables, then converting the truth table to positions, with a link to the implementation. After failing I went and looked at the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5531264/5374625) and saw they were fairly similar (with one being upvoted and accepted). The other answers amount to 'Use Boyer-Moore' and 'Use Knuth-Morris-Pratt {$link}'. So I am confused as to why 'Use Truth Tables {$info about linked code} then turn the truth table into positions {$link}' is less acceptable. Or should all 3 answers be deleted? Where should I draw the line to avoid failing a similar audit again?

I do think the answer deserved vote down, but my efforts lately have been mostly housekeeping focused, so I'm stingy with my answer downvotes to keep me able to access the review queue (until I find time to answer some more questions)