# Link + Direction = No Longer a Link-Only Answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

Yesterday I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649400/5958455) as NAA because it looked link-only to me, and I was NOT surprised to see it's declined. (Yeah, flagging these old upvoted answers makes me feel absolutely normal to have those flags declined - I'm used to it.)

> [image: Visible state]

The answer contains no more than merely a "link title" and the link

### Why I think it's LOA

As Cody Gray said in comments:

> ... The link text tells you exactly where to find the information, down to the section number and exact title in the manual. ...

IMO, Stack Overflow requires answers to be **self-contained**. The answer, to me, is only a link, or strictly speaking, two - one HTML link, one general link.

The answer could be rewritten as below with the precise meaning and content:

> You can find the answer in GNU `make' manual, 6.8: *Defining Multi-Line Variables*
>
> Here's a link to it: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multi_002dLine

The link text in the original answer is the first paragraph in the rewritten answer. According to [Shog9's visualization of LOA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/5958455), it's not an answer - it's a direction to an answer:

[image]

The second part, the real link, the HTML link, is *per se* link-only.

Therefore, the answer contains no direct information at all. It contains no more than two *directions to find an answer* - one real link, one *text direction* telling readers where to find. It is NAA by definition.

Then the argument turns into:

#### Does a link with a direction to finding the answer, together, disqualifies themselves from being LOA?

Comment: Yeah. That's not link-only. The link text tells you *exactly* where to find the information, down to the section number and exact title in the manual. If the link ever did go down, anyone would be able to find it. Don't miss the chance to make it better by editing the relevant information in yourself.

Comment: It’s a little on the edge this one. If the top answer has included a proper GNU manual reference I might have deleted it but right now it’s the only proper documentation reference of the page!

Comment: @CodyGray The answer is still nothing more than a signpost of where to go to find the *actual* information, which would appear to fall in the [4th category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcpV2.png) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)? Without the link, the answer boils down to "See documentation on X" (when the question is "how to X") Useful as a comment, but doesn't seem like an answer

Comment: [Difference between "there might be beer down the street" and "the house beer at tomersh's pub is good"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288055/please-define-link-only-answer#comment165606_288056). Deleting this answer doesn't make the site a better place. There is, however, a way to make the site a better place: edit it. That doesn't require a moderator's intervention. @cer

Comment: @CertainPerformance note that [Shog includes a “look at <manual for preg_split>, third argument” in the “is an answer” category](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: *"What's the current policy of flagging old-time LOA?"* - the same as it has been for several years, and it is still ripe with edge cases that trip people up ;)

Comment: @CodyGray If the question can be answered by simply listing a chapter number in the manual, then the question as whole should probably be deleted. In this case, the question is fine, answers can and should be fleshed-out _on site_, not by linking external examples. In addition, GNU manuals are notoriously bad and incomplete, often failing to explain usage properly. Summary: this a typical link-only answer that adds no value and should be deleted.

Comment: So, @Lundin, you don't like the beer at tomersh's pub? ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray GNU documentation is rather like wanting a beer and getting served a Budweizer.

Comment: @CodyGray I have updated this question in regard to your comment. Please check again

Comment: Another dupe target: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306765/am-i-evaluating-link-only-answers-correctly

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think what's being asked here (if the answer only directs you to a manual, is it link-only) is covered there. The link text tells you nothing about what's being asked, except that it's covered in the manual.

Comment: My understanding is that what's important is for the answer to live on site. Do we genuinely consider "go read chapter X in a book" to be a good answer? Cause without the link, that's what's left.... and it's pretty bad, imho.

Comment: @Patrice Mods have the ability to convert to comment, which can comply with the answer requirement while preserving the useful content.

Comment: @Patrice no, not a good answer, but according to Shog9 definition it is an attempt to answer, hence you should not flag otherwise, if you don't like it you can still dv and with 20k also eventually delete vote.