# Correct answer deleted with no reason

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63463427/402366) was deleted by a moderator without any comment or reason.

The answer is the correct documented way of achieving what the user was asking and it was deleted by someone that, as far as I researched, has no experience in the subject of the question.

> [image]

I looked for a way to report this issue, but couldn't find one.

Comment: If your answer was mostly copy/pasted from a third party source, particularly without attribution, then you create liability for the platform to claims of plagiarism. This can cause a mod to delete. But that’s speculation: include the body of your original answer in this question, so we non-10kers can see the details and give you meaningful feedback.

Comment: My answer contained a link to the product documentation where everything is explained and has been an accepted answer before.

Comment: Oh! With the screenshot this is clear. This is an example of “your answer is in another castle”. See this Q&A: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/273503

Comment: @DanBron how so? *"register asynchronous code as a Page Task"* is an attempt to answer, sure it requires effort on OPs side, but it *is* an attempt.

Comment: @Nick All the reasoning is given in the link in my prior comment.

Comment: No! It points to the documentation. The top of the article states "
14 minutes to read". I would writing a long plagiarizing answer if I wrote all that.

Comment: @DanBron that reasoning only applies when there is *only* a link, the given text is enough to tell OP what to do. Sure it could be a *better* answer, but it does qualify as an answer

Comment: I couldn't care less about points and I would even comment on something I know nothing about. The wrong answer was marked as correct and the correct answer was deleted. How is that helping users?

Comment: @yivi, "Without the link, there is not much use for that answer" only shows that you know nothing about the subject, because it says everything that needs to be said. And it's complemented with a link to the docs.

Comment: @DanBron I disagree. This isn't a link-only answer. OP summarized the solution and posted a link to **the documentation**. This is a _sufficient_ answer. Whether or not it's a good answer and whether or not it can be improved, is up for debate but I don't think it should've been deleted.

Comment: I see these Answers in Late Answers. And they show up when bots are trying to find "Not an Answer"s. They appear to be just above the minimum requirement to not be removed. I don't understand why there's no elaboration on the Answer. It seems that one is forced to do the click-through. I want to remove it.. and put it as a comment instead, but I'm no moderator :)

Comment: @41686d6564 - A “you should do this” answer without explicitly explaining how to do “this” isn’t helpful.  The screenshot clearly shows it was a link only answer. It wouldn’t have take much effort to provide more explicit instructions. **I am very familiar with ASP .NET**. That particular question doesn’t actually have an accepted answer by the way.

Comment: @SecurityHound _"A link-only answer is an answer that contains no information apart from a link to another site. The hallmark of a link-only answer is that it is impossible to evaluate **even the potential usefulness** of the answer without actually following the link. It notably does **not** mean "a short answer containing a link", although folks are often confused."_ -- [Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288056/8967612).

Comment: Moreover, IMO, documentation links are somewhat special. Yes, you shouldn't post the link on its own, but a short straightforward sentence that points to the right direction along with the link is sufficient to make "the answer" _an answer_.

Comment: @41686d6564 - I disagree.  Microsoft is notorious for moving documentation but never redirecting old documentation links to their new location.  Without the link, the answer isn't helpful.

Comment: @SecurityHound which is why the answer contains enough keywords to be able to google. It's a low effort answer which I would definitely never upvote, but it's an attempt to answer nonetheless.

Comment: @SecurityHound it has happened, in fact, regarding "classic" ASP.NET. "notorious" is a bit harsh. Do you have any other cases of documentation moved without redirection?

Comment: @Gimby low effort? It's like the 1000$ for hammering the nail. $1 for the hammering, $999 for knowing that nail needed to be hammered.

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Of course I do, how about every piece of documentation, that wasn't moved to docs.microsoft.com.  Even for those pages that were moved.  You are told it was moved, but when you click on the redirection, it doesn't actually take you to the new location.  I spend my life on docs.microsoft.com I am aware of it's shortfalls.

Comment: @Security Hound: To be fair, they are much better now. PowerShell documentation redirects correctly (though there is some uncertainty about the PowerShell version)

Comment: C'mon, edit your answer and add a short code sample how to register and the whole debate will be over.

Comment: Agree @TadeuszKopec, an effort that seems especially small when compared with the effort expended on this thread.

Comment: @OrangeDog, it didn't answer the first time it was posted in a comment to this question and still isn't now. The bottom line is, how does that help the user when the answer to their question is deleted?

Comment: @PauloMorgado It does answer it. We don't care about helping one specific user, we care about helping as many people into the future as possible. Your answer was deleted because it does not count as an answer, as explained in the linked question.

Comment: @PauloMorgado also that link had not been posted in a comment yet. This demonstrates that you've not even read it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado nobody knows what a "page task" is because it's a term you appear to have made up. It's certainly not mentioned at the documentation you insist has all the answers.

Comment: @PauloMorgado It would have helped had you actually _asked a question_. It seems that the moderator angle of your case is substantially different to the close dupe but you failed to be specific enough to prevent it.

Comment: The article is long and boring, if you added sample code I'd vote to undelete

Comment: @DonCruickshank, I don't understand your point. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. With all those *you know nothing about the subject* comments, I doubt you'll get any help here. Your answer is a link only one, and deserves a downvote if not deletion.

Comment: @oguzismail, I'm sorry if it ever came across that I was seek for help for myself. I'm advocating on behalf of the user that was denied of an answer based only on aesthetics.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Sure. It seemed to me that you were going to ask a question as to why a _moderator_ deleted your question whereas most people were treating this as "why was my question deleted". I can't tell what your asking at the moment because there's no actual question yet and we're left to make up our own.

Answer (score 11):

I checked the flags and it looks like this particular answer was deleted because it was a duplicate answer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403375) (also deleted). Both answers are [little more than a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), hinting at what what the answer could be. And we see *hundreds* of these a day. To respond to a comment

> "register asynchronous code as a Page Task" is an attempt to answer, sure it requires effort on OPs side, but it is an attempt.

Not so much. That's a hint at best. For most mods, if they see a comment with a link posted as an answer, there's a high chance it's going to get deleted. The funny thing taking a moment to quote something relevant from the page itself would make this more than a mere link and an acceptable answer. As if someone wanted to prove the point, [this answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63464188) succeeded in filling in the gaps to form a proper answer.

> I looked for a way to report this issue, but couldn't find one.

Meta posts for questions about mod activity are fine. If you want to expand your answer, you can still edit it and then raise a mod flag for undeletion. Be sure to reference this Meta if you do.

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to explain to the O.P. this very same thing. But my lord, it has been difficult! Should I delete my answer to let your (arguably) better answer shine?

Comment: Nah. Leave yours up. It's a good answer

Comment: @Machavity [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403375/402366) was the start of a discussion the lead the OP to say "IT WORKS!" on the last comment. Page tasks are the way to do it, but the user had other issues. I'm glad I could help, even if it's lost for ever. But when you're right, you're right.

Answer (score 9):

Reading the [help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) section, you can find the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

It explicitly states:

> **Provide context for links**
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

As you can see, it says to "**always** quote the most relevant part [...]", which you didn't do.

I believe this may have been why the answer was deleted, as I see no other reason for it.

---

---

**FROM HERE ON NOW, THIS IS PURELY MY OPINION**

Currently, these are the following flags for answers:
[image: Flags for answers]

Your answer is more fitting as a comment instead of an answer.

You did try to answer, but you didn't put the *juice* of the answer in the answer itself.
That's like asking a question and putting part of the code on pastebin.

As a comment, I think this is fine. As an answer, I think this is a link-only answer and provides little value, in it's current state.

You probably can have it undeleted by adding the "missing content" (code sample as well).

You don't need to copy-paste the whole entire content of the link. Just describe the process in simple and easy terms.

Comment: Wait what? Where did the VLQ flag reason go? Because I used that reason for blatant link-only answers (like: "Read this blog article...").

Comment: @Filnor I have absolutely no idea at all. I just went to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63502603/animating-a-box-shadow-text-shadow-on-a-circular-path and clicked on the flag link for the answer.

Comment: I just did a cross-check on the answer and the Late Answers Review Queue, there it does exist. I guess the flag is only applicable for a specific amount of time after the question was posted.

Comment: That is very strange, if that's the case. I did find this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286971/where-is-the-very-low-quality-flag Maybe it is somewhat applicable?

Comment: I'm sorry @IsmaelMiguel, but I can't get any juice out of this answer. Don't worry, I won't downvote or delete it. Would you care to show me what is the relevant part of that article to the question? The answer to the question is "With ASP.NET Web Forms you have to register asynchronous code as a Page Task". There's nothing more to be said about that. The link to the documentation is to help anyone to get there directly without having to search for it. Until now, no one knowledgeable of the subject has refuted it as being a good answer. Everyone is complaining about aesthetics.

Comment: @PauloMorgado It's not aestetics. 1- It's a **mandatory** part of an *answer* with a link. 2- It completes the answer and gives it meaning, even 20 years from now, when there's no more .Net. 3- "With ASP.NET Web Forms you have to register asynchronous code as a Page Task" makes no sense as a stand-alone answer. Just describe it properly and put a code example and be happy forever. It isn't aestetics. I couldn't care less if your answer looks like it came from the best bakery in town. Your answer can't stand on it's own. But is a very good comment. Also, feel free to downvite, if you wish.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, the question or the answer has no meaning outside of .NET. So 2 is void. Can you provide what would make sense as a stand-alone answer in this case. This is a concrete case about a concrete answer to a concrete question. No generalizations, please. To state "makes no sense as a stand-alone" you have to prove it with knowledge. Can your? "looks like" is just an ignorant way to downplay my knowledge. Can you give me the address of that bakery?

Comment: "Can you provide what would make sense as a stand-alone answer in this case." <-- No. But my answer here is an example of an answer that fulfills the requirements for an answer. "To state "makes no sense as a stand-alone" you have to prove it with knowledge." <-- Without Googling, your answer doesn't make sense to someone who doesn't know about this. And since O.P. made a question, it's obvious that O.P. doesn't know about it. "downplay my knowledge" <-- this has nothing to do with *you*, but with your answer to the post. Stop taking it as a personal attack. I don't know who you are. [...]

Comment: [...] All I know is that your answer doesn't follow the requirement to **always** quote the important content from a provided link. your answer is just pointing to where the answer is. All you need to do is add a title, copy a code example, change it a bit to fix O.P.'s needs and move on. If you find any answer I've written that doesn't conform to this, I will edit it. But just understand this: This is nothing about *you*. Just *your answer*. Nothing less, nothing more. That's all.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm here to help the users, not to do their work and not for personal fame or glory. And you just proved again that this is all about aesthetics. You didn't provide any sound technical reason. If I filled the answer with a bunch of mambo-jambo it would confuse the user, but it would make you happy. What you're saying is that stack**overflow** is all about cerimony, not content.

Comment: It's actually about content. Sadly, yours is lacking on that front. Mandatory content that should be present, but isn't. And notice that I said **AN EXAMPLE** or **CODE SAMPLE**. I never said to do someone's homework. And I never said to fill it with [technobabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technobabble). I've always said to just provide a simple description with easy terms. Thinks that even those who are initiating to learn English or coding can understand reasonably well. How is this aestethic? This place is to teach and learn, not do display your hubris...

Comment: No, it's not about the content. You're making it all about the size of the content. I did provide a "simple description with easy terms", it's not my fault that you don't see it that way. Again, this is a complex issue and requires further investigation from the user. It's not hubris if I know what I'm talking about and you don't. Unless you recognize it's all a ceremony and aesthetics and I'm, definitely, in the wrong place. There a great difference between teaching and doing other people's work.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the *amount* of content. You didn't provide a "simple description with easy terms". You didn't copy the important part of the link, as required. Just look at the end of John's answer: Bits of code to explain how to make it work! And even credited **you**. Your answer is just a link to somewhere. If the only correct part is that last part mentioning you, then John should edit out the rest of the stuff, making his answer **considerably smaller**. Again, it isn't the amount of content, or you, or aesthetics. It's the lack of the mandatory content.

Comment: The answer was deleted by a moderator and so arguments on the quality (e.g. if the answer was too short, bad advice, too esoteric, etc.) are irrelevant as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DonCruickshank I agree that those are irrelevant. Moderators don't delete answers with low quality or based on the correctness of the advice (unless in extreme cases). They would downvote. If an answer was *deleted* by a moderator, it must have been because the anwer doesn't follow *some* guideline. In this case, from what I see, the answer doesn't provide a quote to the important content in the link. That's all im saying! That's all that's important to me, in this case.

Comment: How about if the answer didn't follow the answer quality guideline :wink: BTW, finally SO seems to swing back from anything is an answer, to "you must prove yourself a worthy answer".

Comment: @Braiam I don't know where you're trying to get...

Comment: If this was 1-2 years back, there would be a bigger drama and your answer would be downvoted to hell, and the answer restored because "it _is_ an answer"

Comment: @Braiam Oh, you can bet that. But I'm fine with the downvotes. (Even if it was 1-2 years ago) I believe it doesn't make my answer less right.

Comment: Somehow people equal popular with being correct.

Comment: @Braiam It's the upvotes. The upvotes draw more upvotes.